# How to make options in Jenkinsfile reusable across other Jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've 55 Jenkinsfiles and in every Jenkinsfile I'm using the below block as common, Is there anyway to make this options block re-usable across all the jenkinsfiles?

```
options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr:'30'))
    ansiColor('xterm')
}
```

**Tried - Method-1**
Tried to wrap the options with script block and reading the options from the groovy function, that didn't work as usage of script is not permittable without steps & stage block.

```
options {
    script {
        code= load './options_section.groovy'
        def res = code.options_section()
    }
}
```

`options_section.groovy file:`

```
def options_section(){
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr:'30'))
    ansiColor('xterm')
}
return this
```

Any suggestions/ideas to make the options section of Jenkinsfile (declarative pipeline) reusable? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: HI @gopa-vasanth, Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve with the buildDiscarder method ? 
If this is supposed to be common for multiple jobs, you can add that to a dsl groovy template and seed your jobs accordingly  instead of using it in the Jenkinsfile, if your objective is to delete builds older than 30 days.

Comment: Hi @Param J, Yes, Its for deleting builds older than 30 days, Can you link me any resources which helps me to understand in implementing dsl groovy template and seeding jobs?

Comment: Sure. You can access the DSL groovy API from this link (if you have the DSL-groovy plugin installed)- https://<your-jenkins-url>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.properties.PropertiesContext.buildDiscarder and expand the code for it and add the same in a dsl  groovy file along with your job parameters and seed your job. More details on the DSL groovy plugin usage can be obtained from [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl).